# get unique views for specific posts

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I need to show monthly unique views count for specific pages. So for reaching that I did below:

```
$fullArray = array();
$productIds = '100,200,210,220,255'; /* these are specific product ids */
$idsArray = explode(',',$productIds);
foreach ($idsArray as $unique_id_item) {
    $currentUniqueViews = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT DISTINCT IP as all_uniques, DATE_FORMAT( insertion_date, '%b' ) as 
        month_name, DATE_FORMAT( insertion_date, '%Y-%M' ) as full_date FROM
        daily_unique_views WHERE page_id = '".$unique_id_item."'
    ");
    if($currentUniqueViews){
        $fullArray[] = $currentUniqueViews;
    }
}
$encodedArray = json_decode(json_encode($fullArray), True);
var_dump($encodedArray);
```

And above returns this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Dec"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-December"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Oct"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(12) "2016-October"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Nov"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-November"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "122.12.12.122"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Dec"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-December"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Dec"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-December"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Nov"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-November"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Dec"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-December"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Nov"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-November"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Dec"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-December"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(12) "71.111.1.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Dec"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-December"
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["all_uniques"]=>
      string(13) "111.11.11.111"
      ["month_name"]=>
      string(3) "Dec"
      ["full_date"]=>
      string(13) "2016-December"
    }
  }
}
```

How you notice, array contains duplicated arrays. For example, below array repeats 5 times.

```
array(3) {
    ["all_uniques"]=>string(13) "111.11.11.111"
    ["month_name"]=>string(3) "Dec"
    ["full_date"]=>string(13) "2016-December"
}
```

How can I find and remove those duplicated arrays so that my unique views will be counted properly and in this case this ip (111.11.11.111) will be repeated only once for december and only once for november.

I tried below but it doesn't give me desired result and some ips are missing in array:

```
array_diff_assoc( $encodedArray, array_unique( $encodedArray ) );
```

Any ideas please?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried to use count() function. Count works fine, but duplicated IP count is still in that final count. My query looks like this:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP) as all_uniques, DATE_FORMAT( insertion_date,
'%b' ) as month_name, DATE_FORMAT( insertion_date,'%Y-%M' ) as full_date FROM
post_daily_unique_views WHERE page_id = '".$unique_id_item."'");
```

Comment: I think you should use `COUNT` function in your query. Additionally, you might be able to use `GROUP BY` clause to perform the database operation in a single query.

Comment: could you please show me some example? As I tried both and no luck yet. @Maximus2012

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have tried ?

Comment: I've updated my question. Please check @Maximus2012

Comment: So each unique IP should be counted as 1 visit, correct ?

Comment: I think it might be your `month_name` and `full_date`fields in the updated query that are creating problem. Try the updated query without those fields ?

Comment: When you use `COUNT` and `DISTINCT` functions like this, fields like `insertion_date` lose context. What are you probable looking for is something like `last_insertion_Date` or `first_insertion_date` which you can get by using `MAX()` or `MIN()` functions or something similar.

Comment: Additionally, you can maybe move the `insertion_date` field to a WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes, each unique IP should be counted as 1 visit for each month. Because  same IP can be unique for both months @Maximus2012

Comment: Did you try the things that I mentioned in my previous comments ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But I need `month_name` and `full_date` as I'm collecting data in the chart and need to show monthly views @Maximus2012

Comment: `month_name` and `full_date` corresponding to what ? If you are counting unique visits from an IP then month/date would lose meaning. Can you update your question with the structure of your table and the desired output ? You can also try adding a `GROUP BY` clause for month and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Try this query? `SELECT IP, COUNT(DISTINCT IP) as all_uniques, DATE_FORMAT( insertion_date,
'%b' ) as month_name, DATE_FORMAT( insertion_date,'%Y-%M' ) as full_date FROM
post_daily_unique_views WHERE page_id = '".$unique_id_item."' GROUP BY IP, month_name, full_date`

Comment: This doesn't refer to your question but I wouldn't query in loop. That kills your pages speed with many bullets. I would try to rethink this aproach. Maybe theres a way to build the SQL in the loop and query after.